# SalesForce release management - standard mechanism?

Tags: deployment, release

Today we do not have a release management process for SFDC releases. I read a lot of articles on the subject but I don't find the best way. There is a lot of tools to do that: Flosum, AutoRABIT, Copado, CloudMax, sfOpticon, Force.com Migration Tool.

We think to use the Migration tool with SVN and the DataLoader to automate all the process and make Continuous Integration with Jenkins. The idea is that we would like to have :

- a sandbox for each developer
- a sandbox (QA-Integration) to validate the code (SF best practices convention, naming convention,...)
- a sandbox (UAT) for users tests
- a sandbox (staging) to validate migration to production
- production

What we want to avoid is to take too much time for the prod deployment, found errors in the last step (UAT-staging), found dirty code in another environment than development and we would like to easily roll-back, compare environment, rebase an environment... We think that with the migration tool and svn we can achieve it without encountering too many difficulties but I want to be sure before I implement all the process. So has someone already implemented a similar process in his organization? Has someone scripts example? If not what do you suggest as a proper process for managing SFDC releases according to our needs?

Thanks in advance for your answers en your help.

Answer (score 7):

Answer to your question will be based on the personal opinion and I know that  opinions of different people in community may differ.

But I used such process and I'm pretty happy with it. So, you can read about my personal experience with such process [here](http://www.pavelslepenkov.info/?p=174). Also I added a development process scheme which I created for one of my project.

[image]

I don't know what else I can add to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Pavel mentioned, each business will have their own preferences and factors which will affect what 'good' will look like for their release management process.

If you're looking for a clear, simple guide to release management you might like to check out our new whitepaper. It runs through the tools, processes and Salesforce configurations that will help you create an effective release process. I think it could be a really useful resource for you to help formulate your ideas.

You can download it free here: https://gearset.com/salesforce-release-management

(FYI, I'm a part of the Gearset team, but we've written the whitepaper about processes, not tools. You could apply the models in it to whatever tool you end up choosing.)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you go through the [Trailhead Application Lifecycle Management Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/alm_deployment) which has a high level overview of this material with links to more specific resources. I'd also recommend you join the Release Readiness & Feature Adoption Group in the Salesforce Success Community. They provide many resources and do webinars on this subject. Just last month (Aug 2015) they did a webinar titled [Sandbox Best Practices](http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/bSj2fTHVM3VHDQsA0dYy9A) that was well worth the time to view. Many of the same questions you're asking were discussed during the webinar along with the Q&A at the end of it.

There was a follow-up supplement published to group regarding questions they weren't able to respond to during the webinar. Unlike the webinars that you're used to viewing that are created by Salesforce, this Group allows Q&A to continue beyond the allotted time for the webinar then publishes a summary of the discussion the following day in a file to the group. The file is named [Feature Focus - August 2015 Sandboxes Questions and Answers](https://success.salesforce.com/06930000005PvX6?retUrl=%2Fchatter%2Fhandlers%2Flistview%2Ffile%3F_dc%3D1441807525614%26type%3Dfile%26filter%3Drecent%26fldr%3D%26linkDesc%3D%26customFilterParams%3D%26isSearchSupported%3D).

Answer (score 0):

This is Aleem from AutoRABIT. I'd recommend you to go through the following link for SVN setup and connectivity:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Force.com_with_Subversion_for_Team_Development

AutoRABIT has strong integration support for Version Control Systems (SVN, GIT, TFS & Perforce) and can fast-track your processes by empowering you with following capabilities:

a) Fetch uncommitted changes from Salesforce and commit directly to SVN using AutoRABIT.

b) CI jobs creation from SVN

c) Compare, sync Salesforce org and SVN

d) Fetch changes from your repository based on date, revision or tagged check-in’s and deploy them to your Salesforce environment.

Incase you need further assistance, please feel free to write to us at support@autorabit.com, our Support Engineers will get in touch with you.